# How Date range between numbers works in teradata

Tags: teradata

Need to ask if the dates are between numbers then how it works. 
For eg.,

Date1-date2 between - 3 and 3

Regards, 
Bhavini

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the number of days between two dates:

```
select DATE <date1> - DATE <date2>
```

That will return an integer representing the number of days.

To see if that is within a certain range:

```
select case when (CURRENT_DATE - DATE '2018-05-10') between -3 and 3 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' END
```